# Rails 3 i18n how to *not* escape newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, haml

I'm using i18n in my .text.haml mailer templates and I want to have a string in en.yml that has a newline but t() is always escaping them even if I use html_safe or suffix the key name with _html.

Is there a way to do this??

```
p3_html: >
    You love monkeys:
     \n- You look like one
     \n- Your smell like one
     \n- Your account has been flagged
```

In my html.haml template:

```
!= t('emails.post.twitter_forbidden.p3_html').html_safe
```

No matter what the \n are escaped.  I can't use %br or anything else because these are text templates.   I know I could split this into 4 i18n strings but that would be really sad.

BTW, I checked and it is i18n escaping, not haml.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this:

`t('emails.post.twitter_forbidden.p3_html').html_safe.gsub("\n", '<br/>')`

As far as I know, this is the only way.

**Edit**

Actually, after some digging, I found the `simple_format` helper.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: I actually want the \n, I'm just getting \\n.   Your answer still will work.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I apologize -- I misunderstood. I'll leave my answer as-is for any other people that might find it.

Comment: A little correction, it should be `t('emails.post.twitter_forbidden.p3_html').gsub("\n", '<br/>').html_safe`

Comment: Thank you! This answer is extremely helpful, but had to use @RustamA.Gasanov 's suggestion of reversing the `gsub` and `html_safe` calls.

Comment: Hey, I would like to know if someone found a solution to exactly keep the `\n` characters without escaping them. I don't want to replace them by `<br/>` or `\\n` tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of options here:
As mentioned above, simple_format will help.
Format your yml file like so:

```
    p3_html: |
      Some text:
      - Point 1
      - Point 2
      - Point 3
```

And then use

```
   =simple_format t(:p3_html)
```

This will give you something like

```
    <p>Some text
      <br>
      - Point 1
      <br>
      - Point 2
      <br>
      - Point 3
    </p>
```

Or if you want each line a new paragraph:

```
    p3_html: |
      Some text:

      - Point 1

      - Point 2

      - Point 3
```

Which should give you this:

```
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>- Point 1</p>
    <p>- Point 2</p>
    <p>- Point 3</p>
```

or something like this is more flexible

```
    <% t(:p3_html).each_line do |line| %>
      <li>= |line|</li>
    <% end %>
```

Enables you to put in different formatting:

```
    <li>- Point 1</li>
    <li>- Point 2</li>
    <li>- Point 3</li>
```

Final option is to use an array in yaml:

```
      p3_html: 
        - Some text:
        - - Point 1
        - - Point 2
        - - Point 3

    <% t(:p3_html).each do |line| %>
      <p>= |line|</p>
    <% end %>
```

Possibly cleaner, though I think it will play merry hell with commas, and the advantage to the above version is that you can switch between formats without needing to modify your yaml

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up just using tags in locale files like this:

```
a:
  b: "Some <br /> thing"
```

And then within the template I make them [`.html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe):

```
<%= t('a.b').html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I18n just uses yaml and yaml can have arrays. :-)

So I would explore using an option like this.

In your yaml file you'd have a key called p3_html

```
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Lists_of_associative_arrays
p3_html:
- some text
- some more text
- some more more text
```

And then in your haml view you'd have this HAML code:

```
= t('p3_html').each do |x| 
  %p= x
```

Or in one line if you prefer

```
= t('p3_html').each {|x| haml_tag :p, x }
```

Also remember if you move this into a helper you'll probably have to utilize the haml_concat helper in front of your ruby variable. I'm not for certain.

You'll also have to adjust the relative/absolute naming of your translate yaml variable t('p3_html') to your app's naming.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just do this to get the text in a new line:

en.yml

```
long_text: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

  Consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

app/views/sample/file.html.erb

```
<%= simple_format t(:'long_text') %>
```

See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format